# Specflow Query - I want to use BeforeStep to put a line into a log report and so I need a way to get the name of the current step

Tags: specflow

Specflow Query - 
I want to use BeforeStep to put a line into a log report and so I need a  way to get the name of the current step.

Comment: Currently the name of the current step is not stored in any of the "contexts", so it is not possible to get to this information in the BeforeStep. I think this can be only solved if you either change the source code of SpecLog or you write a plugin.

Comment: SpecFlow compares poorly in this regard to something like [Behave](http://pythonhosted.org/behave/) for Python. Forced to use SpecFlow for a project and missing Step context sorely.

Comment: As an aside, I'm attempting now to just count the current step utilizing `BeforeScenario` to reset a counter, increment it on each call of `BeforeStep` and then parse the feature file to identify which step is the current one.. Will try to post some code if successful

Comment: Please see [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/26731361/97614), which might provide you with an option to do this until the next specflow build.

Answer (score 0):

Check out the Aspect Orient Design product - http://www.postsharp.net/ 
Examples - http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/337564/Aspect-Oriented-Programming-Using-Csharp-and-PostS

This lets you inject code into every method call (e.g. logging)